# Positive-Operator-Valued Measure (POVM)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I have to solve the following exercise about POVMs, but the problem is, I still don't understand what a POVM really is...

a) suppose $E_1$ and $E_2$ are POVMs on $\mathcal{Z}_1$ and $\mathcal{Z}_2$, respectively, both acting on the Hilbertspace; let $q_1, q_2 \in [0,1]$ with $q_1 + q_2 =1$. Show that $E(B):= q_1E_1(B \cap Z_1)+q_2E_2(B \cap Z_2)$ defindes a POVM on $\mathcal{Z}_1 \cup \mathcal{Z}_2$.

b) Suppose Experiment $\mathcal{E}_1$ has distribution of outcomes $\langle \psi \vert E_1(\cdot) \vert \psi \rangle$, and $\mathcal{E}_2$ has Distribution of outcomes $\langle \psi \vert E_2(\cdot) \vert \psi \rangle$. Describe an experiment with distribution of outcomes $\langle \psi \vert E(\cdot) \vert \psi \rangle$.

c) Give an example of a POVM for which the $E_z$ do not pairwise commute. $\textit{Suggestion}$: Choose $E_1(z)$ that does not commute with $E_2(z')$ for $\mathcal{Z}_1 \cap \mathcal{Z}_2 = \emptyset$.